# What is the name of the transverse white line that separates different time-limited parking zones?

Tags: california, legal-terms, parking

I parked on a street that has 2 parking zones: all-day (with bi-weekly street sweeping) and two-hour. Painted on the street is a single six-inch-wide six-foot-long transverse white line that, I believe, separates the zones.

I parked on the "all day" side of this line, but received a ticket for breaching the two-hour conditions, citing "parking within 100 feet of the two-hour zone sign". I have previously appealed a similar ticket for parking in exactly the same place, and succeeded in obtaining a statement that this parking spot was part of the all-day zone.

What is the name of the transverse white line so I can talk with intelligence? Is it legally defined anywhere? I couldn't find it in the CA MUTCD or Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just came back from my hearing. Turns out the white line on the street means nothing and was "left there by some contractors." Parking signs do not give permission (such as parking "all day"), they only restrict. So, the most restrictive parking sign within 80 feet applies to your car.

My previous ticket was excused because the block registers as 2 blocks, 3000 AND 3100, and my car was incorrectly cited as being in the half that was over 80 feet from the two-hour sign.